# mysql datetime to format to string HH:MM

Tags: mysql, .net, vb.net

I have a mysql database which I am pulling a datetime from, for sake of ease the datetime returned from mysql is:

```
2013-12-30 12:01:32
```

I am trying to save a string to show 24 hour style HH:MM

I am finding a lot of documentation regarding translating .net to mysql however I am finding little to no documentation on the other way around.

Comment: Are you trying to save a time value to a MySQL table or format a MySQL time value as a .NET string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
  Convert.ToDateTime(textBox.Text).ToString("HH:mm")
```

or

```
Dim dateValue As DateTime = "2013-12-30 12:01:32"
Dim formatForMySql as string = dateValue.ToString("HH:mm")
```

Comment: excellent, 
Convert.ToDateTime(mysqldbfile).ToString("HH:mm") 
worked excellently

Answer (score -1):

Use String.Format

```
Dim dt As DateTime = DateTime.Parse("2013-12-30 13:01:32")
Dim time24 = String.Format("{0:HH:mm}", dt)
Dim time12 = String.Format("{0:hh:mm}", dt)
```

Note the difference between 24 and 12 hour is the capital `HH` vs lower-case `hh`